# Insert batch data in column type "Person" on Sharepoint list with Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, sharepoint-list, batch-insert

I'm using a batch to insert data on Sharepoint List.
The field on Sharepoint is a Person type so when I try insert the email (type string) through Power Automate the follow error is showed:

"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
CONTENT-TYPE: application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8

{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"pt-BR","value":"A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of a navigation property; however, a 'StartArray' node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was expected."}}}"

I'm think that's is because the Person type need more data besides email (the only information that I have), but I don't know how resolve it.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the `[{'Key':'i:0#.f|membership|johndoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com'}]` format with the claims value?

Comment: Thanks for you answer! 
The item was created:

" HTTP/1.1 201 Created
CONTENT-TYPE: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8
ETAG: "dc33ed31-ec39-41ca-aac5-b83359043886,1" "

Despite it having successfully created, the sharepoint shows the field without value.

Do you have any idea what could be going on? (I add a image in post)